# Class variable not working for some reason? Python

Tags: python, class

```
class Note:
     nextseqNum = 0
     def __init__(self):
        self.text        = str
        self.dateCreated = datetime
        self.dateRead    = datetime
        self.description = str
        self.category    = str
        self.priority    = int
        self.hidden      = bool
        self.seqNum      = nextseqNum
        nextseqNum       += 1
```

For some reason it is throwing me

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'nextseqNum' referenced before
>   assignment

I don't understand why. That is how you make a shared class varaible right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shared class variable needs to be accessed on the class -- It doesn't become a local variable in class methods (which explains the error message):

```
self.seqNum = Note.nextseqNum
Note.nextseqNum += 1
```

---

there are some shortcuts:

```
self.seqNum = self.nextseqNum  # Not found on self, so looked up on class.
Note.nextseqNum += 1
```

works because if a name isn't found on an instance, python then looks at the class.  If you don't want to name the class explicitly:

```
self.seqNum = self.__class__.nextseqNum  # for new-style classes, type(self) == self.__class__
self.__class__.nextseqNum += 1
```